# Using か in casual speech

Tags: usage, particles, particle-か, casual

There are definitely many questions about the usage (or lack thereof) of か in casual speech. Although it is relatively common in anime, it sounds harsh, maybe rude in everyday casual speech.

Alright, understood. My question then is: when *do* we use it? I know of embedded questions, such as:

> 何を買ったか知っている？
>
> "do you know what they bought"

But I'm not interested in those. I know of 何か and 誰か as distinct words, but I'm not interested in those either. I think I've heard things like:

> あの女の子が僕を好きなのかと思ったけど

Where the か is in a quoted clause, and I am interested in those, as well as things like:

> できるか

Which I understand can mean something like "as if I could do it".

Basically, besides embedded questions, when might we actually use か in casual speech?

Edit: although sundowner's answer is helpful, I'd also like to hear maybe a more informal description, with examples, of when casual questions use か, since sundowner's answer only says that questions can take か.

Comment: Also if the sentences I've presented are really odd, please do correct me. Like specifically the first two since I've presented these as "probably correct".

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? E.g. 終助詞 definition at https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8B/#jn-34860

Comment: I don't think telling people to read japanese dictionary entries is in general the best idea, given that most people including myself don't have the level of japanese required to get a nuanced understanding from a dictionary entry in the language they are learning.

Comment: maybe helpful.  https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-of-the-sentence-ending-particles-in-Japanese-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: I guess casual question simply drops か. So you are asking when a question uses か AND sounds casual?

Comment: Using informal endings, like obviously with 丁寧語 we say like 昨日何を食べましたか but we as I understand it don't use か when we say 昨日何を食べたか, if that makes sense. か is definitely dropped in casual questions as I understand it, but I'm interested when we leave it in, or other cases where we're not speaking with 丁寧語 but use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, foreigners' grammar does not seem to focus much on each particle per se. This is more or less a translation of the dictionary definition linked in the comment.

Sentence-ending か could mean:

1. Question marker
2. Question marker, with implied negative.

- どうしてそんなことしなければならないのか Why on earth do I have to do it (I don't think I have to).

3. When denying the interlocutor's assumption

- そんなこと知るか How am I supposed to know that (= I don't know!)

4. Let's

- ご飯食べようか Let's eat

5. Urging (mostly appears as ないか)

- さっさと宿題やらないか Why not start working on your homework (The speaker is urging to do the homework)

6. Surprise, exclamation.

- 誰かと思ったら君だったか I was wondering who it was, and ah, it was you.

The distinction between 2 and 3 is a bit fuzzy.

か in かとおもう is still a question marker, but practically it means *maybe*. E.g. your sentence means *I thought maybe the girl liked me, but*.

できるか could be a simple question (rising tone) or means 3 (decreasing tone, usually stressed). Particularly in a manga, it is a common scene where A tells B to do something impossible and B says できるか!, which means *How could I?*

---

Hopefully the following clarifies your question.

Consider the following

1. きのう何を食べましたか？
2. きのう何（を）食べました？
3. きのう何（を）食べた？
4. きのう何を食べたか？

As you say in the comment, 4 is weird. But note 2 is possible in ます form. Also in 2 and 3, を tends to be omitted, which is possible in 1 as well.

On the other hand, all of the following are possible.

5. きのう学校に行きましたか？
6. きのう学校に行きました？
7. きのう学校に行った？
8. きのう学校に行ったか？

5-7 are common with decreasing politeness. 8 is possible, but sounds strongly masculine, like from someone superior in some sense. I don't know a proper English word, but in this case for example a father can say 8 to his child.

One possible explanation is that non-ます-form + か sounds masculine, and in case of wh-question like 4, it sounds almost military. For example, an officer could say to subordinates この非常事態を何と心得ているか *What do you think of this emergency?*

Comment: "foreigners' grammar does not seem to focus much on each particle per se" sorry, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Riolku I mean I can't find online article that lists meanings of particles, particle by particle. Most online grammars seem  to be explaining by sentence form.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks. For the invitation usage, is it always with volitional? Could we write デートに行かないか? Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: デートに行かないか is perfectly fine for inviting, but technically it is more of a question. It should be similar to *Don't we go out together?* which is semantically an invitation.

Comment: I think you mean "why don't we go out together". Can you compare 行かないか with just 行かない?

Comment: Yeah, but just literally. 行かないか sounds masculine. 行かない? sounds more casual and gender-neutral.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify, basically although your answer is very helpful and reminded me of usages I'd forgotten there are two at the top that I'm not super clear on still.